# How to prevent lights from becoming weaker and noise increases when using multiple objects with emission in viewport

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, texturing, lighting, emission

So I wanted to make a street scene using lights from street lamps and the buildings but when I apply the emissions on the buildings the lights from the street  lamps become weaker and harder to see. The noise also increases.
Here is the viewport scene eithout the emissions from buildings.
[image]
Here is the scene from the viewport with the building emission added
[image]

Comment: Have you tried a full render with enough samples?

Comment: @Leander I have and everything seems fine, but its difficult when setting up the scene in the viewport

Comment: Definitely. You need enough samples for the viewport. Quick tricks are to (1) set the Viewport Samples to `0`, that way the viewport keeps on rendering and to (2) only render a small portion of the screen with a render border (Ctrl + B) for speed.

Comment: Ahh I understand, I tried it and it improved . Thanks for the tricks @Leander :)

Comment: You can also temporarly decrease the total max bounce, that means that the light rays won't  bounce that often and decrease the noise massively. Also remove checkboxes for Reflective and Refractive Caustics.

Comment: @VeloFX Okay ill give it a try, thanks for the advice.